# Get socket handle to use for comparison later

Tags: c++, sockets, handle

I hooked some socket function of a game. Then can get the receive and sent data from sockets inside that game. The problem is: There are more then 1 socket.

How could I get the handle of the FIRST socket created? I hooked the function SOCKET, like this:

```
SOCKET GameMainSocket;

SOCKET _stdcall WSAAPI nSocket(int af,int type,int protocol)
{
     UnHookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "socket", KSocketHook);
     GameMainSocket = socket(af, type, protocol);
     HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "socket", (LPVOID*) nSocket, KSocketHook);
     return GameMainSocket;
}
```

But then, later, when I try to compare it within hooked send and recv function, like this:

```
int __stdcall nSend(SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len,int flags)
{ 
  if (s = GameMainSocket)
  {
    // Allow send
  }
}
```

The code is just skipped and all the checks are true.

** My real quetion is: How could I identifie each socket created by an application?

Thanks in advance!

PROBLEM FULLY SOLVED.

My code now is:

```
if (s == GameMainSocket) 
{
// The magic goes here, encrypt packet with XOR (server does the same)
    char* buf2 = (char*) malloc (len);
    memcpy(buf2, buf, len);
    //buf2[0] = buf2[0];
    buf2[0] = buf2[0] ^ int("x") % 255;

}
```

Comment: You should NOT be unhooking and re-hooking `socket()` every time `nSocket()`  is called. That introduces a race condition - think of what would happen if another thread happens to call `socket()` while you have unhooked it.  When you hook a function, save a pointer to the original function so you call it directly when needed.

Comment: I understand your point, but, should I stop unhooking and then hooking again all the function send, recv, etc?

Comment: Yes for all of them. Hook them once and leave the hooks in place, and then have the hooks call the original functions directly when needed, don't unhook to make those calls. Whatever API hooker you are using should provide you access to the original functions when hooking them. It has to know what they are so it can unhook them.

Comment: I got that Remy, big thanks!

Comment: Eii Remy, could you tell me could I make a backup of the function hooked? So then wouldnt need to Unhook and Hook the function again. My HOOK CODE: http://pastebin.com/NLQaAN8G  

Thank you!

Comment: You need to [read up on how detouring and trampolining work](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=68568). Your current backup code is missing one vital piece - an unconditional jump into the original function. With that, your hook (the detour) can call the original function when needed by simply calling the trampoline, which will execute the instructions you backed up and then jump into the original function to execute the rest of it. You should use an existing detour/hooking library instead of writing your own manual hook code.

Comment: Also, why are you using `(Read/Write)ProcessMemory()` to read/write memory in your own process? You only need to use those functions when reading/writing memory in OTHER processes. You have directly access to your own process's memory.

Comment: Could you tell me a good hooking library? I am trying to use detours in Dev CPP but didnt find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (s = GameMainSocket)
```

is doing assignment which will return the assigned value, which will be true if it is not 0.
Did you mean to do the following?

```
if (s == GameMainSocket)
```

Comment: I need to get the handle of any socks, then I tried to hook socket and connect to get the handle of 's' and store it. Then later, in recv and send functions, I compare 's' from send or recv from the 's' of function socket or connect. But doesnt work.

Comment: I still dont understand your question. If you create a socket in nSocket and assign it to GameMainSocket and you want to compare the s in nsend to the GameMainSocket, which is the socket you created in nSocket, then you can just use if (s==GameMainSocket). If you need to create multiple sockets, then you need some sort of data structure (list, vector, map) to hold all of the socket handles and any other information you need.

Comment: Ok, I have another ideia. How could I get the IP of the remote host that I am trying to connect when the function connect() is called?

This way I could check if that socket has the IP I want, and then set SOCKET GameMainSocket equal to 's' and then verify it later in send and recv function

Comment: The remote IP:Port are passed to `connect()` in its `sockaddr*` input parameter. You would have cast that parameter to `sockaddr_in*` or `sockaddr_in6*` based on the parameter's `sa_family` field (`AF_INET` for IPv4, `AF_INET6` for IPv6, respectively) and extract the IP:Port accordingly.  Alternatively, you can use `getpeername()` on any `SOCKET` at any time to get a `sockaddr` for its remote IP:Port.

Comment: OOOh I got it! Thank you Remy